# Can I simplify many $.fn. calls with javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using datatables and the following was recommended to be added to my code:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sWrapper = 'no-margin last-child';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sInfo = 'message no-margin';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sLength = 'float-left';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sFilter = 'float-right';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sPaging = 'sub-hover paging_';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sPagePrevEnabled = 'control-prev';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sPagePrevDisabled = 'control-prev disabled';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sPageNextEnabled = 'control-next';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sPageNextDisabled = 'control-next disabled';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sPageFirst = 'control-first';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sPagePrevious = 'control-prev';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sPageNext = 'control-next';
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sPageLast = 'control-last';
```

I don't understand this syntax. Can someone explain what it's doing. Also is there a way that I can combine all of these rows. The first 30 columns are all the same.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand (maybe [MDN - Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) helps)? And yes, you could use `$.extend`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/.

Comment: Shouldn't this question go here -- http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @David if you think so, just flag for ♦ moderator attention. Don't comment since that may cause cross-posting.

Comment: @David, no, one of the requirements from the codereview.SE FAQ is that the poster must have written the code him/herself (["Did I write that code?"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#im-confused-what-questions-are-on-topic-for-this-site")).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code is adding properties to `$.fn.dataTableExt` (as I'm sure you can see).  These properties are probably used as configuration strings for the extension as part of a [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) pattern, so that when an often-used value needs to be changed, it doesn't have to be changed in a dozen places.

This code might be improved by using [$.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
    sWrapper: 'no-margin last-child',
    sInfo: 'message no-margin',
    sLength: 'float-left',
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but you can save the instance in a variable and then reference them with a simpler base:

```
var someObject = $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses;
someObject.sWrapper = 'no-margin last-child';
someObject.sInfo = 'message no-margin';
someObject.sLength = 'float-left';
someObject.sFilter = 'float-right';
someObject.sPaging = 'sub-hover paging_';
someObject.sPagePrevEnabled = 'control-prev';
someObject.sPagePrevDisabled = 'control-prev disabled';
someObject.sPageNextEnabled = 'control-next';
someObject.sPageNextDisabled = 'control-next disabled';
someObject.sPageFirst = 'control-first';
someObject.sPagePrevious = 'control-prev';
someObject.sPageNext = 'control-next';
someObject.sPageLast = 'control-last';
```

Answer (score 1):

At the very least you could do this:

```
$.extend($.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {

  sWrapper: 'val',
  sInfo: 'val',
  ...

});
```